# setuptools: build shared library from C++ code, then build Cython wrapper linked to shared library

Tags: python, c++, build, cython, setuptools

We have a bunch of C++ files with classes that we wrap to Python using Cython. We use setuptools to build the Cython extension. This all works fine, we followed the guide here:
http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html

We are basically doing something like this

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(ext_modules = cythonize(
           "rect.pyx",                 # our Cython source
           sources=["Rectangle.cpp"],  # additional source file(s)
           language="c++",             # generate C++ code
      ))
```

We don't like about this that we have to recompile everything, even if only the Cython part changes, `rect.pyx` in this example. In fact we never touch the `.cpp` files, but change the `.pyx` files often.

We would like to compile the `.cpp` files separately into a static or shared libary, then build `.pyx` files independently, which links to the library generated from the `.cpp` files. All this would be easy with `make` or `cmake`, but we want a pure Python solution that uses only `setuptools`. Mock-up code would look something like this:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

class CppLibary:
    # somehow get that to work

# this should only recompile cpplib when source files changed
cpplib = CppLibary('cpplib',
                   sources=["Rectangle.cpp"], # put static cpp code here
                   include_dirs=["include"])

setup(ext_modules = cythonize(
           "rect.pyx",                 # our Cython source
           libraries=[cpplib],         # link to cpplib
           language="c++",             # generate C++ code
      ))
```

Comment: Never used it and seems sparsely documented but there is a `build_clib` command that might work for you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16854066/using-distutils-and-build-clib-to-build-c-library

Comment: Thank you, @chrisb. I looked into the related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16854066/using-distutils-and-build-clib-to-build-c-library?noredirect=1&lq=1, but `build_clib` from distutils did not work, and it was apparently removed from setuptools

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using distutils and build\_clib to build C library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16854066/using-distutils-and-build-clib-to-build-c-library)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a seemingly undocumented feature of `setup` that can do this, for example:

```
import os

from setuptools import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

ext_lib_path = 'rectangle'
include_dir = os.path.join(ext_lib_path, 'include')

sources = ['Rectangle.cpp']

# Use as macros = [('<DEFINITION>', '<VALUE>')]
# where value can be None
macros = None

ext_libraries = [['rectangle', {
               'sources': [os.path.join(ext_lib_path, src) for src in sources],
               'include_dirs': [include_dir],
               'macros': macros,
               }
]]

extensions = [Extension("rect",
              sources=["rect.pyx"],
              language="c++",
              include_dirs=[include_dir],
              libraries=['rectangle'],
)]

setup(ext_modules=cythonize(extensions),
      libraries=ext_libraries)
```

The `libraries` argument builds the external library found in directory `rectangle`, with include directory `rectangle/include` common between it and the extension.

Have also switched the import to `setuptools` from `distutils` which is deprecated, now part of setuptools.

Have not seen any documentation on this argument but seen it used in other projects.

This is untested, please provide sample files for testing if it does not work.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer, this is very helpful. I tried to follow along your example, but it does not work. `ext_libraries` is not compiled by setuptools, only the Cython extension. I get an error like this `ld: library not found for -llibrectangle`

Comment: You may need to manually include the generated `rectangle` object file as an `extra_objects` argument to the extension as the shared object does not get installed anywhere for the linker to find it. Does the object get generated or nothing is built for `rectangle` at all? As above, will need to show complete code to test with, see [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Note that `ext_libraries` should be of type `list(list(str, dict)))` - answer has been updated.

Comment: For anyone else who got confused by this: `python setup.py develop` does NOT build the clib automatically. You need to do `python setup.py build_clib` manually once.

Comment: Close, but not exactly. `libraries` will build archives (.lib) that will be linked statically. So strictly speaking this doesn't answer the question of how to build _shared_ libraries (what I am looking for); however, it does solve the problem for most people so kudos for helping shed light on this area :)