# Distutils: build multiple Python extension modules (written in Swig) that share a method

Tags: python, c++, swig, distutils

I have four C++ files: A.h, A.cpp, B.h, B.cpp, and A.h is included in B.cpp

A.h:

```
#pragma once 
void A();
```

A.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
void A() {
    std::cout << "A" << std::endl;
}
```

B.h:

```
#pragma once
void B();
```

B.cpp:

```
#include "A.h"
#include <iostream>
void B() {
    A();
    std::cout << "B" << std::endl;
}
```

Now I wrote two SWIG inerface files A.i and B.i

A.i:

```
%module A
%{
#include "A.h"
%}
%include "A.h"
```

B.i:

```
%module B
%{
#include "B.h"
%}
%include "B.h"
```

The setup.py file is:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
A_ext = Extension( "_A", [ "A.i", "A.cpp", ], swig_opts = ['-c++'], extra_compile_args = ['-g'])
B_ext = Extension( "_B", [ "B.i", "B.cpp", ], swig_opts = ['-c++'], extra_compile_args = ['-g'])
setup(
    name = "test",
    version = "1.0",
    ext_modules = [ A_ext, B_ext ],
    py_modules = [ "A", "B" ]
)
```

If I type the command below, it will show 'A'.

```
python -c 'import A; A.A()'
```

If I type the command below, the segmentation fault appears:

```
python -c 'import B; B.B()'
```

How could I do to get this command run correctly? Since I don't want to compile B.cpp many times, is there any way except the one below?

```
B_ext = Extension( "_B", [ "B.i", "A.cpp", "B.cpp", ], swig_opts = ['-c++'], extra_compile_args = ['-g'])
```

Answer (score 6):

I changed your files a bit, for clarity.

*a.h*:

```cpp
#pragma once 


void funcA();
```

*a.cpp*:

```cpp
#include <iostream>


void funcA() {
    std::cout << __FILE__ << " " << __LINE__ <<  " " << __FUNCTION__ <<  std::endl;
}
```

*a.i*:

```cpp
%module a
%{
    #include "a.h"
%}
%include "a.h"
```

*b.h*:

```cpp
#pragma once


void funcB();
```

*b.cpp*:

```cpp
#include "a.h"
#include <iostream>


void funcB() {
    std::cout << __FILE__ << " " << __LINE__ <<  " " << __FUNCTION__ <<  std::endl;
    funcA();
}
```

*b.i*:

```cpp
%module b
%{
    #include "b.h"
%}
%include "b.h"
```

*setup.py*:

```py
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension


a = "a"
b = "b"

ext_a = Extension("_" + a, [a + ".i", a + ".cpp"], swig_opts=("-c++",), extra_compile_args=["-g"])
ext_b = Extension("_" + b, [b + ".i", b + ".cpp"], swig_opts=("-c++",), extra_compile_args=["-g"])

setup(
    name="test",
    version="1.0",
    ext_modules=[ext_a, ext_b],
    py_modules=[a, b]
)
```

What happens (simplified) when calling *b.funcB* (only the *stacktrace*, imports left aside). Each step invokes the next:

1. *funcB* from module *b* (*b.py*)
2. *funcB* from module *_b* (*_b.so*, or *_b.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so*)

   - Everything from here happens in *C* (or *C++*)
   - Current *funcB* is **different** than the one from *b.cpp*: it's generated by *swig* and its name is *_wrap_funcB*
   - Previous bullet also applies to *funcA* and *a.cpp*
3. *funcB* from *b.cpp*
4. *funcA* from *a.cpp*

The problem is that the code from step ***#4.*** is not in the module *_b*, and it will fail at runtime. But things are a little bit stranger: the failure (core dump) doesn't appear when *funcB* is called but at module (*b* -> *_b*) **import** time (I think this happens because of *swig*'s behind the scene magic), as seen below.

**Output**:

> ```sh
> [cfati@cfati-ubtu16x64-0:~/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q050938128]> ~/sopr.sh
> *** Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ***
>
> [064bit prompt]> ls
> a.cpp  a.h  a.i  b.cpp  b.h  b.i  setup.py
> [064bit prompt]> python3 setup.py build > /dev/null 2>&1
> [064bit prompt]> echo $?
> 0
> [064bit prompt]> ls
> a.cpp  a.h  a.i  a.py  a_wrap.cpp  b.cpp  b.h  b.i  b.py  build  b_wrap.cpp  setup.py
> [064bit prompt]> ls ./build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5
> _a.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so  _b.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
> [064bit prompt]> PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:./build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5 python3 -c "import _a;_a.funcA()"
> a.cpp 6 funcA
> [064bit prompt]> PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:./build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5 python3 -c "import _b"
> Segmentation fault (core dumped)
> ```

In order to solve it, either:

1. As you pointed out include *funcA* in module *_b* (by adding *a.cpp* in *ext_b*'s source files list). This way, both modules will be self contained (from *funcA*'s *PoV*), each will work independently,  but also *funcA* will be duplicated in both of them
2. Make *_b* depend on *_a* (after all, they're *shared objects*). But that's not how *Python* extension modules are to be used, and it won't work on *Win* (and also on some *Nix* flavors). So, this is more like a (lame) workaround (*gainarie*)
3. Build *a.cpp* into a different shared library (an *.so*, but **not** a *Python* extension module) to be used by both modules. Needless to say that at runtime each of them will require the *.so* to be present

Obviously, to option ***#3.*** is the perfect candidate. But *distutils* ([[Python.Docs]: API Reference](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/apiref.html#api-reference)) doesn't provide the needed functionality *OOTB* (apparently building an extension module and an external shared library that it depends on, is not a scenario that *distutils* aims for), or at least, I couldn't find any. 
There is a *build_clib* module, which offers the functionality of building a **static** lib (to be used by the extension modules), but that would be same as option ***#1.***.

*setup.py*:

```py
import sys
import os
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from distutils.command.build_clib import build_clib
from distutils.command.build_ext import build_ext
from distutils.ccompiler import CCompiler


__win = sys.platform[:3].lower() == "win"
export_symbols_option = "export_symbols"


class build_clib_dyn(build_clib):
    def finalize_options(self):
        self.set_undefined_options('build',
                                   ('build_lib', 'build_clib'),
                                   ('build_temp', 'build_temp'),
                                   ('compiler', 'compiler'),
                                   ('debug', 'debug'),
                                   ('force', 'force'))
        self.libraries = self.distribution.libraries
        if self.libraries:
            self.check_library_list(self.libraries)
        if self.include_dirs is None:
            self.include_dirs = self.distribution.include_dirs or []
        if isinstance(self.include_dirs, str):
            self.include_dirs = self.include_dirs.split(os.pathsep)

    def build_libraries(self, libraries):
        for (lib_name, build_info) in libraries:
            sources = build_info.get('sources')
            if sources is None or not isinstance(sources, (list, tuple)):
                raise DistutilsSetupError(
                       "in 'libraries' option (library '%s'), "
                       "'sources' must be present and must be "
                       "a list of source filenames" % lib_name)
            sources = list(sources)
            macros = build_info.get('macros')
            include_dirs = build_info.get('include_dirs')
            objects = self.compiler.compile(sources,
                                            output_dir=self.build_temp,
                                            macros=macros,
                                            include_dirs=include_dirs,
                                            debug=self.debug)
            self.compiler.link(CCompiler.SHARED_OBJECT, objects, self.compiler.library_filename(lib_name, lib_type="shared"),
                               output_dir=self.build_clib,
                               export_symbols=build_info.get(export_symbols_option),
                               debug=self.debug)


if __win:
    class build_ext_w_dyn_dep(build_ext):
        def finalize_options(self):
            super(build_ext_w_dyn_dep, self).finalize_options()
            self.library_dirs.append(os.path.dirname(self.build_temp))

else:
    class build_ext_w_dyn_dep(build_ext):
        pass


a_name = "a"
b_name = "b"
common_name = a_name + b_name + "common"
swig_opts = ["-c++"]
libraries = [common_name]
lib_common_build_info = {"sources": [a_name + ".cpp"]}
if __win:
    extra_compile_args = None
    extra_link_args = None
    lib_common_build_info[export_symbols_option] = ["funcA"]
else:
    extra_compile_args = ["-g"]
    extra_link_args = ["-Wl,-rpath,${ORIGIN}"]

lib_common_info = (common_name, lib_common_build_info)
ext_a = Extension("_" + a_name, [a_name + ".i"], libraries=libraries, extra_compile_args=extra_compile_args, extra_link_args=extra_link_args, swig_opts=swig_opts)
ext_b = Extension("_" + b_name, [b_name + ".i", b_name + ".cpp"], libraries=libraries, extra_compile_args=extra_compile_args, extra_link_args=extra_link_args, swig_opts=swig_opts)

setup(
    name="test",
    version="1.0",
    libraries=[lib_common_info],
    cmdclass={"build_clib": build_clib_dyn, "build_ext": build_ext_w_dyn_dep},
    ext_modules=[ext_a, ext_b],
    py_modules=[a_name, b_name]
)
```

**Notes**:

- *build_clib_dyn* extends *build_clib* as its functionality had to be modified. 2 methods overridden but only small parts of them actually changed (comments were not copied from the base class methods (*Python**3.5.4*** codebase), in order to reduce the amount of code, but that doesn't really count as a change)
- The task took quite some *distutils* code browsing, as some options are not documented (and I'm not very familiar with it)
- Some *Nix* knowledge was required as well, as things get tricky when loading shared libraries that are not in the system paths, and also keeping things smooth (e.g. not altering *${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}*)
- *build_ext_w_dyn_dep* is similar to *build_clib_dyn* (*Win* only). Since when building a *Win* dynamic link library (*.dll*), 2 files are generated, and in this case they are not in the same dir, library search paths needed some adjustments
- *Python 3* **and** *Python 2* compatible

**Output** (running the above commands again):

> ```sh
> [064bit prompt]> ls
> a.cpp  a.h  a.i  b.cpp  b.h  b.i  setup.py
> [064bit prompt]> python3 setup.py build > /dev/null 2>&1
> [064bit prompt]> echo $?
> 0
> [064bit prompt]> ls
> a.cpp  a.h  a.i  a.py  a_wrap.cpp  b.cpp  b.h  b.i  b.py  build  b_wrap.cpp  setup.py
> [064bit prompt]> ls build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/
> _a.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so  _b.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so  libabcommon.so
> [064bit prompt]> ldd build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/_a.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
>         linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffadb49000)
>         libabcommon.so => /home/cfati/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q050938128/build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/libabcommon.so (0x00007f91cd50f000)
>         libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f91cd18d000)
>         libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f91ccf77000)
>         libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f91ccbad000)
>         libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f91cc990000)
>         libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f91cc687000)
>         /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f91cd916000)
> [064bit prompt]> PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:./build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5 python3 -c "import _a;_a.funcA()"
> a.cpp 6 funcA
> [064bit prompt]> PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:./build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5 python3 -c "import _b;_b.funcB()"
> b.cpp 7 funcB
> a.cpp 6 funcA
> ```

- Added support for *Win* (I guess, it's not very important for the question)

  - Since the module structure is simple, it was possible to do everything at *setup.py*'s level (didn't have to modify the source files)
  - The only extra requirement is that *swig.exe*'s *dir* should be in *%PATH%*

Comment: Did this answer your question?

Comment: It seems like https://github.com/mdavidsaver/setuptools_dso may solve some of the same problems as your `build_clib_dyn`

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Eric. Didn't notice it at the time.